# Angular Error TS2339: Property 'vehicle' does not exist on type 'Vehicle[]'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Angular Error TS2339: Property 'vehicle' does not exist on type 'Vehicle[]'. the error was on data.vehicle.results. Any idea? is the problem on the model Vehicle? I've tried adding vehicle on model sames not working.

## 1 service

```
getVehicles(): Observable<Vehicle[]> {
        return this.http.get<Vehicle[]>(CONSTANST.routes.vehicle.list);
    }
```

## 2 component

```
  getVehicles() {
        this.priceruleService.getVehicles()
            .pipe(
                map(data => {
                    console.log("data :" , data.vehicle.results)
                    return data
                })
            )
            .subscribe(data => this.vehicles = data);
    }
```

## model

```
export interface Vehicle {
    _id: number
    name: string
    Type: string
    Stock: string
    vehicle: any
}
```

## data structure

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECMsg.jpg

Comment: what does `data` look like?

Comment: You are returning Vehicle[] array but while accessing you use data.vehicle. Either change return type as normal object or access data[index].vehicle

Comment: @Manish an array of objects

Comment: @vipulpatel , what do you mean sir , not seem clear to me

Comment: @Mr.MarkTawin then that probably the issue as you are  trying to access `data.vehicle.results` on array of objects. Instead use use index to access the object. So if i'm not wrong data is actually the array you referring by `data.vehicle.results`

Comment: try modifying  `map(data => {`   to  `map((data:Vehicle ) => {`

Comment: does accessing an array of objects matter that causes that error ?

Comment: @edison post your answer so i can upvote if correct

Comment: If you can add a sample value of your `data` i will be able to clarify this properly..

Comment: @Mr.MarkTawin What i am trying to say is you are returning array but you are accessing like object. data.vehicle.results  where data is array of type Vehicle  but you are accessing like object with dot operator. Try using data[0].vehicle like that

Comment: cant we return the data.vehicle.results ? array of objects?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/sbJTbIG , here is the data structure

Comment: data[0].vehicle does not solve the problem either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have data which is not array but you are returning observable of type array. Make it Observable and then you can access :

```
getVehicles(): Observable<Vehicle> {
    return this.http.get<Vehicle>(CONSTANST.routes.vehicle.list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing

```
 getVehicles() {
        this.priceruleService.getVehicles()
            .pipe(
                map((data:Vehicle) => {
                    console.log("data :" , data.vehicle.results)
                    return data
                })
            )
            .subscribe(data => this.vehicles = data);
    }
```

Comment: this implementation is just the same that i want to access is the data.vehicle.results

Answer (score 0):

If `data` is an array of `Vehicle`s, then simply replace

```
            .pipe(
                map(data => {
                    console.log("data :" , data.vehicle.results)
                    return data
                })
            )
```

with

```
            .pipe(
                tap(data => {
                    console.log("data :" , data);
                })
            )
```

Property `vehicle` doesn't exist on type `Vehicle[]` (only on type `Vehicle`), and nothing here has a property called `results`.

(And yes, if a `map` gets data, performs a side effect on them, and returns the same unaltered data, it should be `tap`, not `map`).

Comment: but data is nested that i why I want to access data.vehicle.results

Comment: But `data.vehicle` _doesn't exist_.

Comment: what do you mean it does not exists ?

Comment: `getVehicles()` gets an array. It has all the array properties, like `length`, but it doesn't have a property called `vehicle`.

Comment: but how can i access the nest ?

Comment: pelease check the image url

Comment: Please paste the data structure into your question, it's a piece of relevant data that was missing.

Comment: I have provided it , the url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200331/discussion-between-mr-mark-tawin-and-mbojko).

Comment: do you have now idea about the problem ?

Comment: @Mr.MarkTawin see i have posted new answer by looking at data

Answer (score 0):

OK, your adding of data changes things enough that I'll just write another answer, instead of rewriting. (And BTW it would be nice if you could put the data in post, instead of a screenshot).

First important thing: you're getting TypeScript errors. In other words, compile (or transpile, or build)-time errors. TypeScript has no way of knowing what data will come from the API call and just follows your declarations. Here:

```
getVehicles(): Observable<Vehicle[]> {
```

"Get an observable of arrays of type Vehicle". And when you're then trying to access `data.vehicle` - it's a TS error already, because you declared a completely different structure of data.

The actual structure looks something like

```
interface IVehicleItem {
/* you fill it */
}

interface IVehiclesResponse {
    vehicle: {
        results: IVehicleItem[];
    }
}
```

then, you should be able to

```
getVehicles(): Observable<IVehiclesResponse> {
        return this.http.get<IVehiclesResponse> //...
```

without problem.